# How would I find the mean of object 1 in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm super confused as to how to find the mean of "object1" and really need help. here's a screenshot. I can't find anything online really and can't find help.

[image]

Comment: Some of your rmarkdown code blocks are using three single-quotes `'''` for code-fences, those are incorrect. It needs three backticks `\`\`\`` instead.

Comment: Got it! I changed that. My teacher said to use mean (dat$object1) and I just tried it and it didn't work... is there something I need to add to it? Like backticks?

Comment: *"It didn't work"* says nothing. Did it emit a warning or error? Did R or your operating system crash? Did the neighborhood lights dim? The *picture* (not good) of your data suggests that it is named `mydata` and not `dat`. Welcome to SO, Gracie Hobby! Please learn how to make questions a bit more reproducible by including sample data and code you've attempted; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for good discussion. Also, no pictures of data please, just *real data* (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`dat$object1` refers to a column named `object1` in a data frame named `dat`. Judging from the picture, you don't have a data frame named `dat`. However, you do have a column named `object1` in your data frame. You need to change the first part of `dat$object1`, to make it refer to your data frame. Once you have made that change, you can put it inside `mean()`.